# Difference between two dates in C#

Tags: c#

In a senario I need to find out the difference between two dates.For example Start date is 01/01/2012 and To Date is 01/10/2013  .I need to get the output as 1.9 years.

```
int tDays=(ToDate.Subtract(FromDAte).Days+1);
int years = tDays / 365;
int months = (tDays % 365) / 31;
```

But this calculation is wrong in case of Leap years.

Comment: You forget `c#-5.0` tag.

Comment: Your year count is an int. You cant get decimals

Comment: By `1.9` you mean that you want to format the result as `{year}.{month}` ?

Answer (score 8):

My [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library is built for exactly this sort of thing:

```
LocalDate start = new LocalDate(...);
LocalDate end = new LocalDate(...);
Period period = Period.Between(start, end);
Console.WriteLine("{0} years, {1} months, {2} days",
                  period.Years, period.Months, period.Days);
```

Note that this will *also* deal with the fact that months aren't always the same length - so for example, February 1st to March 1st 2013 (28 days) == 1 month, whereas March 1st to 
March 29th (also 28 days) == 0 months, 28 days.

That will get you months, years and days - I'm not sure where you get "1.9" from based on your example, unless you're using "years.months", which I'd strongly recommend *against* as it looks like you mean "very nearly 2 years".

Comment: I haven't used NodaTime, can you explain how this is different from just going `TimeSpan diff = ToDate - FromDate` and then printing the TimeSpan in any form you want? Is NodaTime just "nicer looking" or is there functional differences?

Comment: @Tobberoth: No, it's a very functional difference: `TimeSpan` is *just* a number of ticks. That means it can't break it into "months" because it doesn't know which month we're talking about, etc. The same `TimeSpan` could represent 1 month, or 1 month and 3 days due to the way that months vary in length. The `Period` type in Noda Time is designed for calendrical arithmetic like this, rather than just a calendar-neutral "this many ticks have elapsed". (We have a different type - `Duration` - for that concept.)

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for my currently project. Nice works.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a DateTime Object with your regarding dates. Then you can create the difference between two DateTimes, the result is a TimeSpan object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
        DateTime date_start = new DateTime(2011, 1, 30);
        DateTime date_end = new DateTime(2012, 2, 29);//leap year

        DateTime tmp_dtStart = date_start;
        DateTime tmp_dtEnd = date_end;

        //FIX FOR LEAP YEAR
        //If the day is the last day of the month just adding 1 day. This might solve the leap year problem.            
        if (tmp_dtStart.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(tmp_dtStart.Year, tmp_dtStart.Month))
        {
           tmp_dtStart= tmp_dtStart.AddDays(1);
        }
        if (tmp_dtEnd.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(tmp_dtEnd.Year, tmp_dtEnd.Month))
        {
           tmp_dtEnd= tmp_dtEnd.AddDays(1);
        }

        DateTime diff = new DateTime((tmp_dtEnd - tmp_dtStart).Ticks);

        int years = diff.Year - 1;
        int month = diff.Month - 1;

        string outStr = string.Format("{0}.{1} years", years, month);
```

I have edited previous code to handle the leap year.

Logic is, (i have used 2 temp date variable without touching the actual date variable)
Checking for the day whether it is equals to last day of the month . If yes then
add 1 to day and it moves to next month.

I have tested few of the dates it is working fine.

Comment: That doesn't take into account leap years

Comment: Or the fact that months vary in length.

Comment: I made some changes for handling leap year.

Answer (score -1):

If all you need is simply a value, you can use `Ticks` property. For example:

```
//Calculate Ticks in one year
var now = DateTime.Now;
var ticksInYear = (now.AddYears(1) - now).Ticks;

//Create some dates
DateTime first = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
DateTime second = Datetime.Today;

//Get the difference
long value = (second.Ticks - first.Ticks)/ticksInYear;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Sorry, missunderstood the question. Corrected.